# Need angular jasmine test case for scrollIntoView function call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is the method I wanted to test but not able to understand how to mock scrollIntoView.
Is there any documentation which can help me to understand jasmine testing.
I am getting error saying ele.scrollIntoView is not a function.

```
scrollIntoViewMethod(): void {
    const offsetTopDiv = '.highlight';
    const ele = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(`${offsetTopDiv}`);
    ele.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'center',
      inline: 'nearest',
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you show your unit test?

Comment: sry alexander I can't show you that but the error I am getting is  ele.scrollIntoView is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understand `el` is a `ViewChild`, then you can mock its `querySelector`.

```js
it('test', () => {
  // assuming that env is set and ready
  fixture.detectChanges();

  // adding spy
  const querySelectorSpy = spyOn(component.el.nativeElement, 'querySelector');

  // creating a stub
  const eleSpy = {
    scrollIntoView: jasmine.crateSpy('eleSpy.scrollIntoView'),
  };

  // setting the return value
  querySelectorSpy.and.returnValue(eleSpy);

  // action
  component.scrollIntoViewMethod();

  // assertion
  expect(querySelectorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('.highlight');
  expect(eleSpy.scrollIntoView).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center',
    inline: 'nearest',
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Satan for the answer, can refer any documentation for jasmine test case so that I can dig little more in it.

Comment: Their api is here: https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/global, and here you can find examples: https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction, it's an old API, but at least have nice examples.

Comment: Thank you satan, really appreciate your help.